# After upgrade in Ubuntu to R 3.4.0 and newest rstudio, rstudio crashes with, "r error 4"

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, rstudio

A few days ago I upgraded from R 3.3.3 to R R 3.4.0, using

```
./configure  --enable-r-shlib
make
sudo make install
dpkg -i rstudio-1.0.143-amd64.deb
```

From command line, R works wonderfully:

```
> R.version

platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.0                         
year           2017                        
month          04                          
day            21                          
svn rev        72570                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
nickname       You Stupid Darkness         
> require(utils)

> .libPaths()

[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/library"
```

However, rstudio crashes upon start-up.  The command line gives:

```
> rstudio

"TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.desktopHooks.notifyRCrashed')"
QIODevice::read: device not open
QIODevice::read: device not open
```

Further, the interface pop-up window says:

```
The R session had a fatal error.

ERROR r error 4 (R code execution error) [errormsg=Error in as.environment(pos) : 
  no item called "package:utils" on the search list
]; OCCURRED AT: rstudio::core::Error rstudio::r::exec::evaluateString(const string&, SEXPREC**, rstudio::r::sexp::Protect*) /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/r/RExec.cpp:302
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled both R and rstudio numerous times, after manually rm -rf ~/.rstudio-desktop and various other folders ~/.R*, as suggested in posts.  Still, no rstudio.
I cannot find any other installed version of R on this machine.
What can I try next in order to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I have *absolutely no problem* using the [prebuilt R 3.4.0 binaries for Ubuntu from CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) along with current dailies from RStudio (and I have a [littler script to fetch them](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/inst/examples/getRStudioServer.r), also see the [matching one for RStudio Desktop](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/littler/blob/master/inst/examples/getRStudioDesktop.r)):

```
R> R.Version()$version
[1] "R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)"
R> rstudioapi::getVersion()
[1] ‘1.1.135’
R>
```

If the R you built yourself does not work, maybe you can try the prebuilt one many of us use?

*Edit:* Now that the question has been formatted, the error of `no item called "package:utils" on the search list` is more apparent.  You may somehow have told R to ignore its own packages.  You need to fix that.  Your installation is essentially crippled.  So with that, do consider the pre-built binaries.  *They work.*

Answer (score 1):

My guess, based on this bit of output:

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/library"
```

Are you trying to use the same library path as you had with R 3.3? This won't fly -- R packages aren't cross-compatible between minor versions of R. You will have to re-install any R packages you want to use with R 3.4.0.

Comment: That is not true as stated.  It generally works---I always "just upgrade" on the work/home/laptop instances of Ubuntu.  _This time_ we need to rebuild packages which combine a) source code _and_ b) use of `.C()` or `.Fortran()`.  Other just work.

Comment: Yes, I have done as you directed above, Dirk, and found that it works, of course, and that some libraries needed to be reinstalled and others did not.  Now I understand why.